# LINQToSQL - Auto Incremented Id Provided - Row not in database

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have a Comments db table

[image]

```
        var c = new comment
        {
            name = message,
            userID = userId
        };

        this.commentDataContext.Comments.InsertOnSubmit(c);
        this.commentDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        this.logger.WriteInfo($"Message: {c.name}");
        this.logger.WriteInfo($"CommentId: {c.id}");
```

Within my log files I do receive an CommentId

2019-11-04 11:06:28,042 [79] INFO  Root [(null)] - CommentId: 271609

However when I do a query on the db table it returns nothing.

Is it rolling back? I have looked at the event viewer but see no errors. As this is on a live server, I hope to not go down the route of turning on tracking as its constantly being hit, so will be like trying to find a needle in a hay stack. Is there another way I can work out why it thinks it has inserted but then roll-backed the change?

Comment: Is this code part of a transaction that hadn't yet committed when you checked the database?

Comment: Ahh it is within a [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)], however I would expect ones from earlier this morning (9ish) should have completed. Will look into it though